# File path issue in mac

Tags: .net-core, filepath, nopcommerce

nopCommerce version: 4.1
I am using nopCommerce version 4.1 on mac os with visual studio for mac, when I run this solution, I get error on creating path.

> Plugin 'Must be assigned to customer role'. Could not load file or
>   assembly
>   '/Users/alireza/Desktop/NopCommerce/Presentation/Nop.Web/Plugins\bin/Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles.dll'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.\n\nCould not load file or
>   assembly
>   '/Users/alireza/Desktop/NopCommerce/Presentation/Nop.Web/Plugins\bin/Nop.Plugin.DiscountRules.CustomerRoles.dll'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.\n\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:

```
 path = Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT
            ? path.Replace("~/", string.Empty).TrimStart('/').Replace('/', '\\')
            : path.Replace("~/", string.Empty).TrimStart('/');
```

Comment: Please do a pull request or create a Github issue.  Have you manage to run NopCommerce on a mac with no issues?

Comment: @ATL_DEV my issue on nopCommerce github github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/3348, yes, I can run nop on mac

Answer (score 0):

in the file opCommerce_4.10_Source/Libraries/Nop.Core/Infrastructure/NopFileProvider.cs

replace the the following function

```
public virtual string MapPath(string path)
```

with the following code :

```
public virtual string MapPath(string path)
    {
      //  path = path.Replace("~/", string.Empty).TrimStart('/').Replace('/', '\\');
       path =  Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT
        ? path.Replace("~/", string.Empty).TrimStart('/').Replace('/', '\\')
        : path.Replace("~/", string.Empty).TrimStart('/');
        return Path.Combine(BaseDirectory ?? string.Empty, path);
    }
```